# javascript fail-safe plugins

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to write Javascript that will run regardless of whether or not other JS code on the site fails? In my experience so far, once the JS throws an error, all other code that's supposed to proceed it doesn't work. Is it possible to write something that will always work? I also will not have control of all the JS code on the site.

Ideas?

Comment: each `<script>` will execute separately, so [a failure in one wont stop another](http://jsfiddle.net/893tw/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it takes some effort. Imagine you're using some framework `f` which has the method `x`. Try this:

```
 <script src="...."> // load the real "f"
 <script>

 if (type f === 'undefined') { f = {}; }
 if (type f.x === 'undefined') { f.x = function() {}; }
 ....
 </script>
```

If the remote script fails to load/execute, `f` will still be defined. The checks in your script make sure you can call `f.x` without having to worry or drown your code in `try{}catch`.

As [zzzzBov demonstrated in his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/893tw/), a failure in the framework script will only abort its execution. After handling the error (usually logging it to the console), the browser will continue with the next `script` element.